# html 5 or jquery player with share functions

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, soundcloud, audio-player

I'm looking for an html 5 player or jquery player with share functions to at least facebook and twitter.  And a link copy function so someone could paste a link in email etc.

Soundcloud is close but on the iphone the share functions for the social sites disappear. And the copy link function defaults to soundcloud instead my own site.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks guys!